# How to have multiple live real time data markers from a php file in mapbox?

Tags: php, json, mapbox

This is the code from my php that updates real live data in my mapbox:

```
$value = array( 
    "geometry"=>array( 
        "type"=> "Point", 
        "coordinates"=> [floatval($longitude),floatval($lat)]
    ) , 

    "type"=>"Feature", 
    "properties" => array(
        "description" => "<strong>Visitor No.1</strong>"
    ) 

); 


// Use json_encode() function 
$json = json_encode($value); 

// Display the output 
echo($json);
```

Pretty print of json data:

```
{
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
            120.92718138599082,
            14.313414704855333
        ]
    },
    "type":"Feature",
    "properties":{
        "description":"Visitor No.1<\/strong>"
    }
}
```

Right now it only gives out 1 live map marker in my mapbox map. Here's a snip of code from my mapbox php file that gets the data from this json_encode file:

```
var url = 'ayyyy.php'; //name of php file that i get the live data from
map.on('load', function() {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        map.getSource('points').setData(url);
          }, 2000);


map.addImage('pulsing-dot', pulsingDot, { pixelRatio: 1.3 });
        map.addSource('points', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': url
        });
```

Right now I want to try a json print like this: (but i don't know how)

```
{
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
            120.92718138599082,
            14.313414704855333
        ]
    },
    "type":"Feature",
    "properties":{
        "description":"Visitor No.1<\/strong>"
    },
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "type":"Feature",
    "properties":{
        "description":"Visitor No.1<\/strong>"
    }

}
```

I tried doing this:

```
 $value = array( 
        "geometry"=>array( 
            "type"=> "Point", 
            "coordinates"=> [floatval($longitude),floatval($lat)]
        ) , 

        "type"=>"Feature", 
        "properties" => array(
            "description" => "<strong>Visitor No.1</strong>"
        ),
         $value = array( 
        "geometry"=>array( 
            "type"=> "Point", 
            "coordinates"=> [floatval($longitude),floatval($lat)]
        ) , 

        "type"=>"Feature", 
        "properties" => array(
            "description" => "<strong>Visitor No.1</strong>"
        ) 

    );
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That JSON doesn't look valid, you have multiple keys with the same name. `$value = array(...` You're overwriting `$value` here. You want/need an array of arrays, something like this: https://3v4l.org/fSeHm

Comment: thanks didn't notice that one the only problem i'm having right now is this [ ] in the outermostpart of the json_encode i need it to be {}
[{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[12.34,45.67]},"type":"Feature","properties":{"description":"<strong>Visitor No.1<\/strong>"}},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[34.56,56.78]},"type":"Feature","properties":{"description":"<strong>Visitor No.1<\/strong>"}}]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the other comentator for pointing the value thing! Realized i had to do this type of pretty print for multiple markers.

```
{
                'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                'features': [
                   {
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -131.21888112093228,
      -26.526198945019374
    ]
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {}
},
{
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      0,
      0
    ]
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {}
}
                ]
            }
```

had to add feature collection part. Thank you

https://3v4l.org/vfAHd
here's the json_encode if anyone's wondering.